# Solutions of a second order nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am in trouble solving the following differential equation:
$$\ddot{x}(t)=-\alpha\dot{x}(t)\dfrac{x(t)}{\left(\beta^2+x(t)^2\right)^{\frac{5}{2}}}$$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constant.
How can I solve it?
Thanks

Comment: Any constant is a solution, so that solves the IVP whenever $x'(0)=0$. Otherwise I doubt you will find a closed form. Try numerics.

Comment: An observation: As long as $\alpha,\beta$ are non-zero, you can introduce appropriate rescalings $x=Ay,$ $t=Bs$ such that the constants disappear i.e. $y''(s)=-\dfrac{y(s)y'(s)}{(1+y(s)^2)^{5/2}}$ for some choice of $A,B$. So the constants really don't matter here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to analytically solve the ODE and express the result on the form of $t(x)$

The huge function found cannot be inverted, so the result is not expressed on the form $x(t)$

[image]

Comment: (+1) That implicit form is simultaneously impressive and rather horrifying.

Comment: Hopping that there is no bug in the horrifying calculus ! (Even with some parts made with the help of symbolic maths soft.)

Comment: One thing that would make the computation slightly straighter is to make some substitution $(x,t)=(Ay,Bs)$ for appropriate $A,B$ in such a way that the constants $\alpha,\beta$ need not be explicitly present. Though I don't anticipate that allowing the final form to simplify.